# How to resolve 'Use dynamically generated dynamic IV' warning in Spring Boot with AttributeEncryptor class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube

This is caught in Sonarlint report. I'm not sure if this is something that can be excluded or marked to ignore in sonar settings. How to get rid of this sonarlint message "Use dynamically generated dynamic IV" in spring boot?

The AttributeEncyptor class:

```
@Data
@Component
@Configuration
public class AttributeEncryptor implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AttributeEncryptor.class.getName());

        @Value("${encryption.initVector}")
        private String initVector ;

        @Value("${encryption.password}")
        private String password ;

        @Value("${encryption.salt}")
        private String salt ;


    IvParameterSpec iv = null;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        if(attribute != null && !attribute.isBlank()) {
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKeyFromPassword(password,salt), iv);
                return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(attribute.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error while encrypting: {} ",e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if(dbData != null && !dbData.isBlank()) {
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKeyFromPassword(password,salt), iv);
                return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error while decrypting: {} ",e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static SecretKey getKeyFromPassword(String password, String salt)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        return new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec)
                .getEncoded(), "AES");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

The @Value comes from application.yaml

```
encryption:
  initVector: 
  password: 
  salt:
```

How to get rid of this? Is Random generator library to have that enough?